# login window come again and again after login with password

Tags: boot, xorg, login, 17.10, syslog

By mistake .Xauthority and .xsession-errror file is deleted from me.I am facing a Login Loop Problem. I entered the correct password, then after few seconds the login window comes again and asks for username and password. The password I use is correct, since when I enter the wrong password it is showing *Incorrect Password*.

Yes I'm able to login Into terminal consol (ctrl + alt + f3)

/var/log/syslog  *Showing Output*

```
anacron[909]: Job `cron.daily' terminated

anacron[909]: Normal exit (1 job run)

snapd[918]: 2018/07/10 09:54:00.601201 storehelpers.go:413: cannot refresh 

snap "core": snap has no updates available

snapd[918]: 2018/07/10 09:54:00.603954 autorefresh.go:388: auto-refresh:         all 
snaps are up-to-date

Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...

systemd-tmpfiles[3830]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.

systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.

systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.

anacron[3855]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-07-10

anacron[3855]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)

gsd-color[2922]: no xrandr-eDP-1 device found: Failed to find output xrandr-eDP-1

gnome-shell[2746]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/endSessionDialog.js 767]: reference to undefined property "checkBoxText"

gnome-shell[2746]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/modalDialog.js 218]: reference to undefined property "GdkX11Screen"

gsd-print-notif[2881]: Source ID 2 was not found when attempting to remove it
kernel: [ 1914.660289] rfkill: input handler enabled

org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2655]: A connection to the bus can't be made

gnome-screensav[2721]: Got disconnected from the session message bus; retrying to reconnect every 10 seconds

evolution-calen[3089]: Error releasing name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx2983x2: The 

connection is closed

org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer[2655]: gnome-shell-calendar-server[2761]: Lost (or failed to acquire) the name org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer - exiting

CRON[4082]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

/var/log/boot.log *CHECKED*

There is no error in bootlog.

/var/log/Xorg.0.log *Output Shows*

```
[   111.252]
X.Org X Server 1.19.5   
Release Date: 2017-10-12

[   111.252] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0

[   111.252] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu

[   111.252] Current Operating System: Linux agamya-anveet 4.13.0-46-generic 
#51-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 12:36:29 UTC 2018 x86_64

[   111.252] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-
generic.efi.signed root=UUID=d7c995c0-986d-4c05-ab79-5687979110b6 ro quiet 
splash vt.handoff=7

[   111.252] Build Date: 15 October 2017  05:51:19PM

[   111.252] xorg-server 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please    see 
http://www.ubuntu.com/support)

[   111.252] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0

[   111.252]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org

to make sure that you have the latest version.

[   111.252] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default 
setting,

(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,

(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

 [   111.253] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jul 10   09:45:07 
 2018
[   111.253] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share   /X11/xorg.conf.d"

[   111.253] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.

[   111.253] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.

[   111.253] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)

[   111.253] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"

[   111.254] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".

Using a default monitor configuration.

[   111.254] (==) Automatically adding devices

[   111.254] (==) Automatically enabling devices

[   111.254] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices

[   111.254] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices

[   111.254] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff

[   111.254] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not 
exist.

[   111.254]    Entry deleted from font path.

[   111.254] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not    exist.

[   111.254]    Entry deleted from font path.

[   111.254] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not    exist.

[   111.254]    Entry deleted from font path.

[   111.254] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not         exist.
```

Comment: `.Xauthority` and `.xsession-errors` will be re-created as needed - you should look elsewhere for your issue. Is the home directory writeable? is the partition full?

Comment: Hi Niranjan and welcome to askUbuntu! Please refine your post and put more information to your post. E.g.: Can you login via a terminal console (ctrl+alt+f3)? Post errors you find in logs  like  `/var/log/syslog` , `/var/log/bootlog` , ` ~/.local7share/xorgs/Xorg.0.log` or use `dmesg` .

Comment: What's the right on the `.ICEAuthority` file ? Be sure that your user can edit it (`sudo chown $USER:$USER .ICEAuthority`)

Comment: yes i did that already then also it's not working

Comment: Just try to remove and reinstall gdm: `sudo apt purge gdm gdm3 && sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop && systemctl restart gdm` @niranjanpawar

Comment: Not working     *sudo apt purge gdm gdm3 && sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop && systemctl restart gdm* @ponsfrilus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)